# C++ Winsock Google Search Query GET Request

Tags: c++, windows, winsock

I want to do a search query on Google through a GET request using Winsock in C++.

Right now the response has scripts and styling, but not any actual search results. The end goal is to be able to retrieve links to PDFs from Google.

E.g. do a search query like this programmatically: www.google.com/search?as_q=Computer+Networking&as_filetype=pdf

This is for learning purposes and I want to stick with Winsock, not any other libraries.

```
#include "pch.h"

#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int error(std::string message);

static int err = 0;
static char buffer[0xFFFFFFF];

int main()
{
    std::string url = "www.google.com";
    std::string query = "Computer+Networking";

    // Store source code response here
    std::string source;

    WSAData wsaData;
    SOCKET Socket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    struct hostent *host;

    std::string GET = "";
    GET += "GET /search?as_q=" + query + "&as_filetype=pdf HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    GET += "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br";
    GET += "Accept-Language: en-US, en; q=0.9, nb; q=0.1";
    GET += "Cache-Control: no-cache";
    GET += "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
    GET += "Host: " + url + "\r\n";
    GET += "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

    err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (err)
        return error("WSAStartup");

    Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (Socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        return error("Invalid socket.");

    host = gethostbyname(url.c_str());

    SockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);

    err = connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr));
    if (err)
        return error("Connection failed.");

    send(Socket, GET.c_str(), strlen(GET.c_str()), NULL);

    int i = 0;
    int nDataLength;
    while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket, buffer, 0xFFFFFFF, NULL)) > 0)
    {
        while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r')
        {
            source += buffer[i];
            i++;
        }
    }

    closesocket(Socket);
    WSACleanup();

    std::cout << source << std::endl;
}

int error(std::string message)
{
    std::cout << "ERROR: " << message << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Look into Google's [Custom Search REST API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest) which provides a much easier programmatic search interface than trying to scrape the front end browser-facing interface.

Comment: @TypeIA This is more for learning than anything else. And if I did use Google API, I would have to use the Bing API (and similar APIs) when expanding to several search engines. But they probably all use JSON and are pretty similar, so I get your point. It's just a feeling of less control when using APIs. Is it really a bad idea to scrape the front-end?

Comment: @TypeIA And hypothetically if many people were to use the program regular API keys wouldn't suffice.

Comment: Scraping the front-end may be very difficult, not a beginner project to be taken lightly. You may need to do HTML parsing, follow links to additional content/resources, and even execute JavaScript to properly render the page; _then_ you still have to search the rendered DOM to get the results. Modern web sites in general are not one-shot make-one-request-and-get-a-result schemes. That's what REST APIs are for.

Comment: @TypeIA I'll go with the REST API as a first then. Thank you.

Comment: You should reset i to 0 each time recv returns something. The condition for the second while loop is i < nDataLength.

Comment: `static char buffer[0xFFFFFFF]` wastes too much memory. Use a smaller buffer.

Comment: @TypeIA Using the APIs is pretty expensive, both Google and Bing. Any other ideas? Preferably free.

Comment: You said this was a learning project. What do you hope to learn? There are other, simpler, free (non-search) APIs you could experiment with. There are also full-featured web client libraries you could use. And there are other things you can do with Winsock to learn that. Don't bite off nore than you feel like you can chew.